# How do I improve this layman question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold-questions

[Is the majority of conjectures confirmed or rejected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452807/is-the-majority-of-conjectures-confirmed-or-rejected)

As a layperson I can think of several cases when conjecture was confirmed but none when it was rejected. For instance

http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/math-whiz-solves-a-master-s-riddle/

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem

Both cases are newsworthy regardless if the conjecture was confirmed or rejected.

How do I improve my question to be more specific?

Comment: This post might be interesting for you: [Examples of conjectures that were widely believed to be true but later proved false](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95865/examples-of-conjectures-that-were-widely-believed-to-be-true-but-later-proved-fa)

Comment: +1 for asking, even though the answer in this case unfortunately seems to be "impossible".

Comment: Thanks Lord_Farin, this is very interesting reading.

Answer (score 3):

As formulated, your question is impossible to answer. There is no "central repository" of conjectures, and no way to determine how large a percentage that gets either confirmed or refuted.

(In one sense, the answer is probably that most conjectures are refuted, if you count temporary ideas held by one or a few researchers in their line of work, but I assume that's not what you meant.)

Comment: Not a central repository but maybe a statistical study or interesting article. I bet I am not the first to wonder about this.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek The OP's parenthesis points the difficulty of circumscribing a canonical list of conjectures. Unless you make this point *much* more precise, I fail to see which kind of statistical study could exist.